# Тюнинг и апгрейд

Tags: семантика, лексика

Мне всегда казалось, что тюнинг - это внешнее улучшение автомобиля, но услышала совсем другое употребление слова. Что точно обозначают эти слова: тюнинг и апгрейд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Апгрейд - да, тут разночтений особых нет, это улучшение устройства путем частичной замены узлов на более совершенные. Не могу сказать что это полный аналог "модернизации", но это детали.
А вот тюнинг... От контекста зависит. Боюсь, прямой перенос англйского значения здесь не совсем правомерен.
В отношении компьютеров и автомобилий это мелкая индивидуальная доработка с целью повышения потребительских качеств. Причем для автомобиля - это в первую очередь, действительно, внешний вид. 
А для звуковоспроизводящих устройств, например, это всего лишь ручка подстройки , ну или совсем точно - действие, такой ручкой совершаемое.  Сейчас правда их может быть десяток - и все со своими названиями.
Что оно могло значить в вашем случае, можно судить только по контексту.

Comment: примерно так: в результате  тюнинга мощность двигателя увеличилась

Comment: Да, здесь это, конечно, "регулировка", "настройка". Обычное вообще, но несколько непривычное по отношению к автомобилю. Если просто в разговоре, то никаких проблем. Вот если это в какой-то обязывающей бумаге, то несколько опрометчиво. Может и правильно, но не всем понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Тюнинг - от *англ.* tuning, т.е. подстраивать. Т.о. это процесс настройки параметров какого-лиго устройства, механизма.

Апгрейд - от *англ.* upgrade. Обычно подразумевается улучшение параметров чего-либо с помощью замены каких-либо составных частей. Синонимично слову "модернизация"